# React native tap on screen

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, node-modules

I need something to tap/click elements in a react native app dynamically using code. Any suggestions? Any node modules? Something like the Javascript HTML DOM `click()` but in react native?

Comment: You don't need any external libraries to do this. Just use Pressable.

Comment: I want to load a webpage into a webview and tap on some buttons using code. I can't do that with injected javascript for this specific webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button#docsNav), [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) or Touchables such as [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity#docsNav) or [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight#docsNav)

Comment: I have to tap on View components using code. These can't do that

Comment: I don't know the context fo your code but if you don't want to call the method directly . You can look at here to do it via a bound reference https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin/issues/60#issuecomment-179130916

Comment: With View use onStartShouldSetResponder. For programmatically click on component use ref.

Comment: I want to load a webpage into a webview and click some buttons. But I can't do that with JS since the page has blocked it. So, I wanna do that by programmatically tapping on the screen.